# vuejs declare global parsing error unexpected token

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm struggling with this error.
this error is occured at

```
error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

   7 | 
   8 | Vue.config.productionTip = false
>  9 | declare global{
     |         ^
  10 |   interface Window{
  11 |     getAlert : any;
  12 |   }
```

I found many answers exist and I followed but it's not working.
Many answers are likely adding this senetence.

```
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
```

but this option is already done when the project is created.

*.eslintrc.js*

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off'
  }
}
```

*main.ts*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
declare global{ 
  interface Window{
    getAlert : any;
  }
}

var vm = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  methods:{
    getAlert(){
         alert(11111)
       }
  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

window.getAlert = vm.getAlert
```

How to solve this problem?
I really want to make a window property.

*common.d.ts(updated)*

```
declare global{ 
  interface Window{
    getAlert : any;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try create a separated `.d.ts` file and put `declare global` there.

Comment: I added and followed your answer. But I 've got this error`30:8 Property 'getAlert' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
    28 |   render: h => h(App)
    29 | }).$mount('#app')
  > 30 | window.getAlert = vm.getAlert` when the declare is out of main.ts